# rewiring toggle switch controled exhaust fan middle of run

Tags: electrical

I'm rewiring an old ceiling exhaust fan in a mobile home. The wires got frayed and shorted out. I foolishly didn't label all the connections when I disassembled it and now can't remember how it was connected. Since it is  in the middle of the run, there are two sets of wires coming in (black/yellow wire in each, no ground-old wiring). I did manage to label the fan wires - one goes to black one to yellow but I'm not quite sure how the toggle switch gets wired. Can anyone help me with how to wire the switch into this fan circuit? Thanks.
Margo

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: I don't see any way to post photos in a message but the link below will take you to them. Right now the two lines are connected since it is in the middle of a run. There isn't really a "box". The wires were just up in the ceiling inside a metal ring that houses the fan.  I think the single black wire was connected to one side of the switch.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hv73b917lxvnuiz/AADOK7UBFBB__WgGy2ir6ndAa?dl=0

Comment: I bought a new switch but tested the old one and it still works.

Comment: You need to figure out which pair is line and which is load. I assume you have more devices or wires down line....and are/were they controlled by the switch? Once you determine this info, we can proceed.

Comment: @Jeff Cates The toggle switch only controls the fan. The oven light is down the line. I do know which pair is coming from the source. How do I wire the toggle switch in?

Comment: You could put your switch on either side of the fan wires. Pick yellow or black, however most of the time your black would be best.  Since your picture shows only a black by itself, then use that as your switched leg, and tie the yellows with your marked yellow wire together.